# java: access can be private

Tags: java, ооп, классы, setter, getter

Есть класс:

```
class Window {
    private int m;
    private int n;

    Window() {
        this.n = 0;
        this.m = 0;
    }

    Window(int m, int n) {
        setM(m);
        setN(n);
    }

    void setM(int m) { this.m = m; }
    int getM() { return m; }
    void setN(int n) { this.n = n; }
    int getN() { return n; }
}
```

Почему intellij idea выдает предупреждение "access can be private" на сеттеры setM и setN? Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста, ведь если я сделаю сеттер приватным, то как его использовать? Что за бред?

Comment: если сделаете приватными, то сможете использовать только в тек. классе. Думаю плдсказка IDE связанна с тем, что класс не `public`. То есть вы не сможете его создать "извне". Вот и рекомендует вам сделать приватными

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41237196/4928642

Answer (score 3):

Идея проверяет, откуда реально делаются обращения и если видит, что указанная область видимости шире, чем используемая. Поэтому выдаётся соответствующее предупреждение. Соответственно, как только ты используешь эти сеттеры где-то ещё, предупреждение исчезнет.

Ну и если эта диагностика тебя в принципе не интересует, её можно отключить в настройках, вероятно так: <kbd>Settings</kbd> <kbd>Editor</kbd> <kbd>Inspections</kbd> <kbd>Java</kbd> <kbd>Declaration redundancy</kbd> <kbd>Declaration Access Can be Weaker</kbd>.